# Google Analytics group events by value

Tags: google-analytics

I have a specific event in GA that tracks value. I want to see how many distinct times each values was chosen. Compare with the following SQL:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(value) FROM event GROUP BY value
```

I could do this by sending pageviews instead of events, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do with events, which are the more correct choice for the situation.

Comment: I recommend using event as this is meant to send data of specific action or value. Can you please tell me what Google Analytic API you're using so I can show you how to do the event tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are literally talking about event values (fourth parameter to event tracking after category, action and label) then you cannot do this, since value is a metric. Metrics are numbers and are added up, so you cannot do a breakdown by metric.

You'd have to send the value as a [custom dimension in the hit level scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) (which obviously would not work for data already collected). Dimensions are strings (even if you pass numbers to a dimension they will still be treated as strings), so you could create a custom report that show how often each specific value has been selected.

Comment: To bad you can't do it the way I described. But this solution is better than doing it with page views.